# iPython notebook not able to read in a data in memory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, greenplum

I have a dataset which I am fetching from Greenplum database and getting into ipython notebook.

The dataset has 550K obs. The size of the dataset is 838MB. Here is screenshot of the same

[image]

One column of this dataset is a text column which for each record has lots of text. However I think in size that would be captured I believe.

However I tried getting the data in python notebook and ran it for more than 12 hours and it couldn't get the data in and eventually said "dead Kernel".

I am not sure why is that when the data size is just 838MB and my mac has 16GB memory.

Please advise.

PS: A previous dataset which was 1.2G was able to get into python notebook in like 15 mins.

Comment: Show us your code for the import. Also as a hack test try exporting the data as a big text file and importing from that.

Comment: """Getting the dataset as pandas dataset """

sql="""
  select 
    * from  analytics.model_data_discharge_updated
"""

model_data=psql.read_sql(sql,conn)

This is the code. Just a sql to get data in

Comment: I would be trying to isolate the problem, before jumping to the conclusion it is a memory issue. Whenever I have had memory issues iPython gives a memory error, not dead kernel. For a start see if you can select less rows:  "select * from analytics.model_data_discharge_updated limit 100". If that works try selecting everything except the text column

Comment: It works for less rows. It worked for 220K rows but took like 6-7 hrs.

Comment: What is your system doing all the time? Busy transferring data over the network? How much memory is your program using?

Comment: You can't compare the 838MB 1:1 to memory usage in your program. First of all, libpq will read the entire result set before handing it over to the application - so you will have twice as much RAM used for some time. And the in-memory presentation in Python might need more RAM per row, compared to the raw data. That said, did you try to read the data in chunks, using a cursor? A few thousand lines a time?

Comment: No I didn't try the chuck thing? How does it work and is it faster?. My also question is if the data size is 838MB, and I have 16gb Mac. I also tried closing all other applications which were running on my system (like chrome browser), Mail app etc so that not much memory is consumed by those. But still it didn't work out and it ended up showing an error after many hours "dead kernel". There is nothing wrong  with code as same works when I sample the data down.